# How to migrate sahi tests to intern

Tags: automated-testing, functional, sahi, intern

I have tests written in [Sahi](http://sahipro.com/) format. I want to convert them to test them using functional testing module of [intern.js](https://theintern.github.io/)

Is it possible to convert the tests written in Sahi format to format that intern.js can understand?

Are there any tools or libraries available for the same?
I could not find anything on the net or in any other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not, as not many people switch testing frameworks.

I haved used some test-migrators between xUnit test-frameworks, but in the end migration by hand was easier. Because in my case I used some features that didn't exist in the other framework.

Possible strategies:

- **100-200 tests**: Migrate by hand, test by test
- **Thousands of tests**: Write your own migrator (first migrate some tests by hand ;-)
- Keep the old tests and only write new tests in the new framework, slowly migrating tests as you see fit.

Probably I would pick the first or the last option. I do not see a lot of trouble with supporting two frameworks for a while. First you have to learn the new framework. After some weeks migration might be much easier and less frustrating.